# Linear-gradient error with working on page

Tags: html, css, colors, background, linear-gradients

I have a problem with website. I create a website with navigation menu that on hover opens, but I can only set background color and I want to set linear-gradient background. I tried to edit code and add some, but isn´t working. Have you any ideas? Can you help me with this problem? Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Domov | Webstránka MENU</title> 
<link rel="icon" href="/minimenu.png">
<meta charset=utf-8>
 </head>
 
 <body style=background-image:blue><div class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xC42G9x/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Trulli" width="155" height="">
           <ul style="background-color:darkblue;">
               <li>
                   <a href="/welcome.php">
                      
                     <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Domov
                       </span>
                   </a>
                 
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Domáce úlohy
                       </span>
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Suplovanie
                       </span>
                 </a>
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                       Známky    
                       </span>
                   </a>
                   
               </li>
               <li class="has-subnav">
                   <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Rozvrh hodín
                       </span>
                   </a>
                  
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-leanpub fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Učebný materiál
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Hry
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
             <p hidden>TU SA ZACINA SUBMENU</p>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 1
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">
                       <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 2
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>
             <p hidden>TU SA KONCI SUBMENU</p>  
           </ul>

           <ul class="logout">
               <li>
                  <a href="/index.php">
                        <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i>
                       <span class="nav-text">
                           Odhlásiť sa
                       </span>
                   </a>
               </li>  
           </ul>
       </nav>
   <zarovnanie>
   <h1>Vitajte, v uživeteľskej sekcii!</h1><br><p>Orientujte sa pomocou navigácie vľavo</p>
   </zarovnanie>
  <style>zarovnanie {
    text-indent: 60px;
    }</style>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
 </body>
   
   <style>@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:darkblue;
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
left:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
 
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
 font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#5fa2db;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Titillium Web';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 300;
 src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
</style>
<style>
h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
h3 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
h4 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
h5 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}
p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

</style>
</html>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you have added a linear-gradient. Where should it go? But you have an 'illegal' background-image on your body element, background-image needs to be of an image not of a color type. (so e.g. a url(...) or a linear-gradient or other sort of gradient).

Comment: @AHaworth 
I removed the linear-gradient because it didn't work. And I also tried to give a linear-gradient for the background-image, but it didn't work. That background-image remained there.

Comment: Could you put the non-working linear-gradient back please because it's difficult to debug something that is basically working (!).

Comment: @AHaworth I'm sorry, but it's been a long time, and I don't remember.

Comment: Could you point out the element that needs a linear-gradient background?

Comment: @AHaworth element <body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear gradient background is wanted on the body element.

A couple of problems in the existing code: the style attribute in body is missing quotes around the value and the background-image has been given a color value but background-images require an image value.

This snippet puts a non-repeating background-image which is a linear-gradient going from top to bottom (the default direction) from blue to cyan.

Note that the body only has the height of its content, you probably want to give it at least the height of the viewport. And of course you will want to change the values within the linear-gradient to get whatever effect you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Domov | Webstránka MENU</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="/minimenu.png">
  <meta charset=utf-8>
</head>

<body style="background-image:linear-gradient(blue, cyan);background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
  <div class="area"></div>
  <nav class="main-menu"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/xC42G9x/f19ada7376b147df815f4dc7438317e0-5.png" alt="Trulli" width="155" height="">
    <ul style="background-color:darkblue;">
      <li>
        <a href="/welcome.php">

          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Domov
                       </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-book fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Domáce úlohy
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Suplovanie
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                       Známky    
                       </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Rozvrh hodín
                       </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-leanpub fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Učebný materiál
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-gamepad fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Hry
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
      <p hidden>TU SA ZACINA SUBMENU</p>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 1
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Submenu 2
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <p hidden>TU SA KONCI SUBMENU</p>
    </ul>

    <ul class="logout">
      <li>
        <a href="/index.php">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                           Odhlásiť sa
                       </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <zarovnanie>
    <h1>Vitajte, v uživeteľskej sekcii!</h1><br>
    <p>Orientujte sa pomocou navigácie vľavo</p>
  </zarovnanie>
  <style>
    zarovnanie {
      text-indent: 60px;
    }
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</body>

<style>
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.main-menu:hover,
nav.main-menu.expanded {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-menu {
  background: darkblue;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
  transition: width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.main-menu>ul {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}
.main-menu li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  color: #999;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.main-menu .nav-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-menu .nav-text {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.main-menu>ul.logout {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,
nav.main-menu li.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,
.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,
.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5fa2db;
}
.area {
  float: left;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
</style>
<style>
  h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  h4 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  h5 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
  
  p {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
  }
</style>

</html>
</div>
```